# How to use @marker data from two different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I have two models: One which contains :city_name, :long, :lat and the other :person_name, :occupation.

How do i create the @marker array using all data from those two different models?

I have managed to put the markers using long,lat,city_name but I fail to figure out how to add  the rest...

Thanks,

Petros

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Array is monkey patched in the gem so you can do:

```
[].to_gmaps4rails
```

Whatever the content of the array.

So, simply build an Array with all data required.

---

EDIT1:
You can set the address of one model exactly the way you want:

```
#Person model
def gmaps4rails_address
  self.cities.first.whatever_relevant_column
end
```

But you can only have one address to take into account. Maybe a gem extension could be to take arrays as argument here.

---

EDIT2:

If you don't need geocoding, so you don't need to add the `gmaps4rails_adress` method.

Simply add the `acts_as_gmappable` with your options (custom lat and lng in your case).

Comment: ...in order to do that, I will have to declare acts_as_gmappable in both models right, since I need infowindow.title from the first and long, lat from the second. Do i have to def gmaps4rails_address in the first model? How? The data are in the second model...

Comment: iq there a relationship between the 2 models?

Comment: let's call the first model Person and the second City:
Person
has_many :cities, :through => :citycols
has_many :citycols, :dependent => :destroy

City
has_many :citycols, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :persons, :through => :citycols

Citycols
belongs_to :city
belongs_to :person

Comment: I am not actually using Geocoding but rather the inverse: I have already long and lat and get the marker based on that. the column names are not standard so I need to add `:lat=>"lat",:lng=>"long"` at least to the City model. Do i also need to do that in the Person model? it doesn't have those columns...thanks for the effort so long!!

Comment: I think I am stuck :( Person since it acts_as_gmappable needs to know lat and lng whatsoever, in order to create the `to_gmaps4rails` json. I added that and I get the error that latitude method doesn't exist for #<Ticket:0x00000102d83d78>.

Comment: lat/lng isn't in this model... mm yep, no easy way to go through this then. You should build json yourself.